# Duplicate and alter contents of file

Tags: duplicate

I'm wondering if anybody could suggest a way to duplicate the contents of a file, in such a way that the duplicates have been altered?

For example, file pre duplication:

```
Nempar|EIJ87098.1  
Ecanceri|ORD93056.1
```

File post duplication:

```
Nempar|EIJ87098.1  
Ecanceri1|ORD93056.1  
Nempardup|EIJ87098.1  
Ecanceridup|ORD93056.1
```

I don't need the alteration to be in any particular location or any particular character. Just that it marks the duplicates.

Currently, I'm simply using:

```
cat file.txt file.txt > file.dup.txt
```

Is there any way I can just add on top of this, or is cat too simple?

Comment: Could you describe what isn't working as you'd want with the `cat` command that you are using? Is it that you'd want to "mark the duplicates"? What does that mean?

Comment: @Kusalananda Sorry, that may have been unclear. Nothing is "wrong" with the `cat` command, it works. I'm wondering if there's a way that when I duplicate the contents of a file, I can add a character to make it different from the original. For example: let's say in the original file I had a line that said 'Space', the duplicate of it could be 'Space1'.

Comment: Did you mean: “@Kusalananda I may have been unclear. While the cat command does what I expected. I am wondering if there is a way that when I duplicate the contents of the file, I can add some characters to make it different from the original. For example: let us say in the original file I had a line that said 'Space', the duplicate of it should be 'Space1'”?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
(cat file.txt && awk -F '|' '{print $1"dup|"$2}' file.txt) > file.dup.txt


cat file.dup.txt 

Nempar|EIJ87098.1
Ecanceri|ORD93056.1
Nempardup|EIJ87098.1
Ecanceridup|ORD93056.1
```

or using sed:

```
(cat file.txt && sed 's/|/dup|/g' file.txt) > file.dup.txt
```

Comment: Perfect, worked a charm and seemed to be the simplest!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `ed` to replace (globally) some given `PATTERN` in `file` with `REPLACEMENT` and then append (`W`) the result to the original contents of `file`

Given

```
$ cat file
Nempar|EIJ87098.1
Ecanceri|ORD93056.1
```

then

```
$ ed -s file << 'EOF'
,s/|/dup|/
Wq
EOF
```

result

```
$ cat file
Nempar|EIJ87098.1
Ecanceri|ORD93056.1
Nempardup|EIJ87098.1
Ecanceridup|ORD93056.1
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using process substitution and `sed`**

Imagine you would modify the input file and append `dup` to the first column:

```
$ sed 's/|/dup|/' file.txt
Nempardup|EIJ87098.1
Ecanceridup|ORD93056.1
```

This substitutes the first `|` with `dup|` in each line.

You could `cat` this modified file with a process substitution of the form `cat <(command)`.

```
$ cat <(sed 's/|/dup|/' file.txt)
Nempardup|EIJ87098.1
Ecanceridup|ORD93056.1
```

Obviously this produces the same output as the first `sed` command.

And with the original input file `cat`ed, it produces

```
$ cat file.txt <(sed 's/|/dup|/' file.txt)
Nempar|EIJ87098.1
Ecanceri|ORD93056.1
Nempardup|EIJ87098.1
Ecanceridup|ORD93056.1
```

You can redirect the output as usual to another file:

```
$ cat file.txt <(sed 's/|/dup|/' file.txt) > file.dup.txt
```